# Shift figures out of margin to the next page

Tags: floats

I have 10 figures which were placed in two columns + 5 rows (side by side). The last two figures were out of bottom margin of page. How can I fix this issue? my preference is to shift figures in last row to next page. Please let me know what command should I use for that purpose?

Comment: Try `\pagebreak[4]` before last two pictures.

Comment: If you will provide the MWE showing your problem, we would easier suggest a solution.  So only can suggest: split your figure into two parts.

Comment: @Mohammad: You can easily put it on two `figure` environments and reset the counter of figure with `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` just before the starting of second figure environment.

Comment: @JagathAR it does work well. But, I did not understand the role of \addtocounter{figure}{-1}. With and Without this line I got same result. Please explain this.

Comment: You have a figure with 10 parts of which 8 parts are in first page and two in second page. If you have used `\caption` in both `figure` environments then you can see that the figure number changed to next number in the second figure enviornment. In order to make the number of figure same that counter reset is required. You can also use `\captionof` command instead of reseting the counter as mentioned above.